# Definition and characterization of trigonometric functions

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I was wondering, throughout one's mathematical education, one is introduced to a various equivalent definitions of sine and cosine, beginning from that of right triangle, then unit circle, then series, and then differential equations.

My question is as follows: what is the defining properties for sine and cosine in the unit circle model? What I mean by that is this:

Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a function such that  $|F(x)|=1$  for all $x$, and  $F$  is  $2\pi$  periodic. I.e., $F(x)=F(x+2\pi)$  for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then is it true that the only functions $f(x),g(x)$ such that $F(x)=(f(x),g(x))$ are $f(x)=\cos x$, and $g(x)=\sin x$?

If not, what more conditions can I impose so that it will be so? Continuity? Differentiability?

Comment: You can make $F(x)=(1,0)$, a constant function, which is continuous and differentiable, and has those exact conditions.

Comment: Thanks, Noy. How about if I add non-constant condition?

Comment: Also, you can make a function that isn't constant that is something like $F(x)=(1,1)$, if $x=\pi+k, k\in N$ and $F(x)=(0,0)$, otherwise

Answer (score 0):

One of the key properties is:

$$\frac{d}{dx} [ \sin(x) ]= \cos(x) $$

Which could be argued is just a special case of both being solutions to the differential equation

$$ \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}= f$$

Up to a multiplicative constant

This highlights some fundamental architecture for both functions beyond periodicity.

For example on the i-axis of the complex plane both sine grows without bound with a shape very similar to the curve $e^x$ despite it's wave like nature on the real axis. It's not immediately clear why these two phenomenon should be coupled together and hence neither by itself characterizes sine.